# javascript hook comparisons

Tags: javascript, hooking

Look at this very basic javascript code:

```
if (s=='abcd')
{
    if (s2='cdef')
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I want to hook all tests: I want to get this:

```
(s,'==','abcd')
(s2,'==','cdef')
```

Is there a way to do this ?

I have tried to put hooks into v8 but it is not easy...

Comment: how is it related to Reverse Engineering?

Comment: Because it is for javascript obfucated purpose